# Best way to return from an async void method if an awaited task is canceled

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm writing a Xamarin.Android app (no domain knowledge is required, though). I have an `async void` method that looks like this:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Some synchronous code

    await SetupEditor(EditorTheme.Default);
}
```

I've written my app such that the task returned from `SetupEditor(...)` will cancel if the user clicks the back button. However, when I click the back button, the app crashes here with a `TaskCanceledException`. I'd like to rewrite this to

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Some synchronous code

    try
    {
        await SetupEditor(EditorTheme.Default);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this without using a try/catch block? I wouldn't want to write 7 lines every time I wanted to await a task like this. Thanks.

Comment: You may of course write the extra code once, then say `await IgnoreCancelled(SetupEditor(EditorTheme.Default))`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish what you're asking. See marked duplicate for some examples. You could also do as the previous comment suggests, writing a method that just encapsulates the try/catch. At best, your question has been answered already (i.e. is a duplicate). It's also primarily opinion based ("graceful" is in the eye of the beholder") and too broad (there are many different ways to approach this type of scenario).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your feedback. The question you linked to is not an exact duplicate of mine, however: it asks how to ignore a canceled task, whereas I'm asking how to `return` if a task is canceled. I think I found a solution using a custom awaitable that never posts the continuation if `Task.IsCanceled` is true; please un-mark this as a dupe so I can post the solution when I have time.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Also, I've removed 'graceful' from the question; the main thing I was looking for was 'concise'.